# Idiomatic way to receive an object or array of objects, transform them, and add to existing array

Tags: arrays, ruby, splat

I have a method that can receive either a single object, or an array of those objects. (The YAML file I'm pulling from sometimes has `foo: bar` and sometimes a list of `foo: [bar1, bar2]`.)

Each time this method is called, it should transform the value or values, and add them to an internal array.

I originally had this:

```rb
class YamlEater
  def initialize
    @foos = []
  end

  def add(o)
    if o.is_a?(Array)
      o.each{ self.add(_1) }
    else
      @foos << FooItem.new(o)
    end
  end
end
```

After I needed to use that pattern in many different methods, I changed it to a non-recursive, more terse version that's splat-heavy and perhaps only a golfer could love:

```rb
  def add(o)
    @foos.push(*[*o].map{ FooItem.new(_1) })
  end
```

I'm thinking there's a more elegant way to accomplish the same goal, and hoping someone will share it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd probably use [`Kernel#Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) and [`Array#concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
def add(o)
  @foos.concat(Array(o).map { FooItem.new(_1) })
end
```

That nicely handles `o.nil?` as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you know, you could eliminate one splat by using [Array#concat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-concat):

```
[1,2].concat([*[4,5]].map { |e| 2*e })
  #=> [1, 2, 8, 10]
[1,2].concat([*4].map { |e| 2*e })
  #=> [1, 2, 8]
```

or [Array#+](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
[1,2] + [*[4,5]].map { |e| 2*e }
  #=> [1, 2, 8, 10]
[1,2] + [*4].map { |e| 2*e }
  #=> [1, 2, 8]
```